# Is there any efficient algorithm to search for the original command given to the turing machine from its output?

Tags: algorithm, search, graph, automata, turing-machines

I have a very high dimensional transition table built for a Turing machine which generates alphabet strings as outputs. Now, I'm trying to make another Turing machine that decodes the output and finds the original input given to the machine.

Is there any efficient way to trace down the rules to find the input? The order in which the rules were applied initially is very important and trying out every possible rule was not ideal. I've thought of doing dynamic programming but this still takes a huge amount of time.

Comment: If there were an efficient solution to this problem, cryptography would be broken, and likely P would be equal to NP. Not saying it's impossible, but it's an open problem in computer science and has been for decades. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P_versus_NP_problem

Comment: I think the last comment qualifies as answer. Especially since it could prompt some  additional discussion

Comment: We don't even know an efficient algorithm to determine the input voltages to a memoryless digital circuit that makes its single output voltage positive.  (That's the Satisfiability problem.)  Finding an input that a Turing machine accepts is even harder, since a Turing machine can have memory.

Answer (score 1):

No.

At least not for the general case you have stated. For a specific Turing machine, there probably is.

The most efficient algorithm I can think of is brute force. The second most efficient algorithm is a neural net trained on a Turing machine. Needless to say both ways are horribly in-efficient (both in runtime and in implementation)